# ng g c componentname - read-only

Tags: node.js, angular, terminal, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm. 
via Terminal I tried to create new component 
Typed:

```
sudo ng g c componentname
```

New component has been created,
*but I'm not able to edit elements*, e.g. to add new sub directory, etc,

because I'm getting error that component is ***read-only***

I'm not sure how I can remove that status, or how can I avoid this to happen again?

Comment: You are editing it inside webstorm?

Comment: Any reason you're using `sudo`? That would result in the files being created as root, whereas you're probably running WebStorm as a regular, non-administrative user who doesn't have permissions to edit those files. Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you should be running the `ng` command without `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, sudo was causing the issue. 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a component, you don't need `sudo`. Simply type `ng g c componentname`.